# C# Selenium - Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException'

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, calendar

Hope someone can help me. I have the following code and I am getting the Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException'

```
IList<IWebElement> WeekDays = Chromedriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay']"));

foreach (IWebElement Days in WeekDays)
{
    string WeekDaysResults = Days.Text;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(WeekDaysResults))
    {
        //Do Nothing
    }
    else
    {
        if(WeekDaysResults == FirstDayOfCurrentMonth)
        {
            Days.Click();
            Debug.WriteLine("Week Days: " + WeekDaysResults);
        }        
    }
}
```

I'm getting the exception on this code `string WeekDaysResults = Days.Text;`

The error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I tried a try catch block but that did not work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this by reassigning WeekDays value,

```
IList<IWebElement> WeekDays = Chromedriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay']"));

foreach (IWebElement Days in WeekDays)
{
    string WeekDaysResults = Days.Text;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(WeekDaysResults))
    {
        //Do Nothing
    }
    else
    {
        if(WeekDaysResults == FirstDayOfCurrentMonth)
        {
            Days.Click();
            Debug.WriteLine("Week Days: " + WeekDaysResults);
        }        
    } 
    WeekDays = Chromedriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class='dxeCalendarDay']"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:

The element has been deleted entirely.
The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

References: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp